# Subtitle editor with words autocompletion

Tags: video, text-editor, video-editing, text

I need an application to create subtitles that can remember words you typed in and help to type them when you type them again.
It may be paid software, any OS would be fine, except Apple's. It may be web.

Answer (score 1):

Not limited to subtitles, [PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) is a text expander program for multiple platforms, including Windows and MacOS. There is a limited free version, although it's not particularly clear what features are not part of the free program.

My sister is a transcriptionist and uses this software to expedite her recording from audio. It works in a simple manner. Common phrases and words, along with formatting, are entered into the editor, with a key phrase assigned to the entry.

As an example "subt" is not a commonly used word or abbreviation. Once entered in the editor, you would type those four letters and a space or tab (I forget which) and the entry would replace them with your desired information/text/formatting.

Your tags indicate that this is for video editing, but the program functions with any text related software.

Comment: Thanks for attitude. I tried FestKeys does the same, but costs $12. Such stuff doesn't help a lot, I would like if editor would remember words by itself propose options to complete (in a drop-down list may be), I've seen such in IDEs.

Comment: What does "thanks for attitude" mean? I've re-read my answer and didn't see any attitude.

Comment: I mean for your attention or proposal.

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor allows this, using two addons:

- lexer for subtitles. In the menu "Plugins / Addon Manager / Install" you will find lexer for SRT subtitles.
- plugin to auto-complete words from the current file. In the same menu: Complete From Text.

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) is a cross-platform, free text editor. It doesn't specifically support subtitle edition out of the box, but you can install the third-party [subed package](https://github.com/rndusr/subed), which supports `.srt` and `.vtt` formats, and has integration with the [mpv](https://mpv.io/) media player.

In Emacs terminology, remembering words that you've typed is called [dynamic abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html). Out of the box, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> completes the word under the cursor to the nearest word it finds that begins with the same prefix. For example, in this answer, after `b` here, it completes “begins”; after `bo`, “box”. After a space, it looks for the nearest occurrence of the previous word and inserts the word that was immediately after that occurrence. There's also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> which offers all completions that begin with the prefix you've already typed for example, after `b`, it offers “begins”, “box” and “but”. You can load the bundled package [hippe-expand](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand) to enable fancier dynamic abbrevs, although I think this is mostly useful to complete words from other open files, which is useful for programming but perhaps not for typing subtitles. Also, you may prefer to define your own abbreviations ahead of time (for example, for proper names), using the (non-dynamic) [abbrev facilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html).